# Автоматическая отправка SMS в интернет-магазине

Tags: joomla

Уважаемые участники форума, подскажите ваши наработки по данной теме (в сети читал, но будет полезно мнение профи): существует интернет-магазин на Joomla+VM (пришлось использовать данный движок по соображениям цена-время). Стоит задача: отправить клиенту СМС о том, что его заказ принят к обработке. Предварительно приняли решение реализовать так: подключаем мобильник к компу "владельца" сайта, программа периодически опрашивает базу, выбирает новые заказы (проверка номера телефона естественна) - далее даем на мобильник AT-команды для отправки СМС. Если кто-то работал по подобной теме, прошу подсказать.

Comment: [SMSC.RU](http://SMSC.RU)

Comment: Это нужно заключать договор с сотовой компанией. Но это неизвестно.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Я принял свой вариант. Участникам форума по-поводу моего вопроса поставил "плюсы", в том числе и Вам (именно "Вам", а не "вам"). При всем уважении - я знаю как "отмечать исчерпывающий ответ" (причем кликая не по "галке", а по чеку (англ. check)). По данной тематике хорошая статья на http://vrtp.ru/index.php?showtopic=7216 . Спасибо за комент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть программа SimpleSMSLite. 
Можно искользовать по принципу. Пишешь сам программу, которая создает временный тесктовый файл с текстом своего СМС. В ini-файле указываешь где он будет находиться.
http://lite.simplesms.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите сервис отправки SMS - [sendmsg.ru](http://sendmsg.ru)

Цены вроде маленькие, да еще и бесплатно интегрируют в Ваш сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, почему бы не попробовать подключиться к сервисам которые давно работают. К примеру, [smsclub.mobi](http://smsclub.mobi). Отправлял через http шлюз на них. Все отлично, навреканий никаких.